# Name for quadratic functions with no linear term

Tags: polynomials, terminology, quadratics

Is there any special name for a function of the form $ax^2+c$

(i.e. a quadratic function with no linear term)?

"centered quadratic" or something?

Comment: Maybe, "pure quadratic" ? In Germany , there is a name "rein-quadratisch" for such functions.

Comment: Without the constant term, you have a quadratic *form*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As hinted by Peter and confirmed by Web search, this is called a *pure quadratic*. https://develacademy.com/pure-quadratic-equation/

Comment: Obviously you have a source, but "pure quadratic [in one variable]" would make me think of $ax^2$, not $ax^2+c$.

Comment: @MarkS.:  many other sources agree. $ax^2$ is a quadratic *form*. And a *pure cubic* is $ax^3+b$.

Answer (score 8):

I've never heard of such a term.  If I had to make one up, I would borrow terminology from cubic equations and call it a ["depressed" quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic).

Comment: It also appears in the quadratic equations, when you "complete the square".

Comment: @YvesDaoust True.  It feels a bit different to me because we rarely reassign the variable name, though.

Comment: In fact, the first step in the resolution of the quadratic, cubic, quartic and even quintic equations is depression.